# Beautiful soup 4 constructor error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am running python 3.5 with BeautifulSoup4 and getting an error when I attempt to pass the plain text of a webpage to the constructor.

The source code I am trying to run is

```
import requests from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup

tcg = 'http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/deck_search_result.asp?Format=Commander'

sourcecode = requests.get(tcg)

plaintext = sourcecode.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
```

When running this I get the folloing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/magic_crawler/main.py", line 11, in <module>
soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 202, in __init__
self._feed()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 216, in _feed
self.builder.feed(self.markup)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 156, in feed
parser = BeautifulSoupHTMLParser(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.5 is an *alpha release* (the first beta is expected this weekend but isn't out just yet at the time of this post). BeautifulSoup certainly hasn't claimed any compatibility with 3.5.

Stick to using Python 3.4 for now.